# How to sort typed arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, typed-arrays

For example I have typed array like this:

```
var a = new Int32Array([3,8,6,1,6,9]);
```

When I try to call `a.sort()`, it doesn't work.

What is the best way to sort typed arrays?
What about performance, can we sort typed arrays faster than regular arrays?

Comment: Have you tried `[].sort.call(a)`?

Comment: @Felix Kling: ^ the answer (I'd rather use `Array.prototype.call` though)

Comment: ES6 introduced `TypedArray.prototype.sort`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37684611/1647737

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript array methods are defined in such a way that they are applicable to any *array-like* object, not only to actual instances of `Array`. So you can use:

```
Array.prototype.sort.call(a, function(a, b) { return a - b; });
```

The custom callback is necessary because JS sorts the values lexicographically by default. See also [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063007/218196).

Comment: I have compared sorting typed array this way, and regular array. It doesn't seem to have any significant difference in speed. Why is that? Shouldn't it be sorting typed array faster than regular array?

Comment: @dartfish `Array.prototype.sort` itself is extremely slow due to the [obnoxious semantics it needs to implement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11). You are better off implementing a specialized sort yourself if you have even a little concern about performance.

Answer (score 3):

The ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification introduced a [.sort() method for typed arrays](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%25typedarray%25.prototype.sort).

```js
var a = new Int32Array([3, 8, 6, 1, 6, 9]);
console.log(a.sort()); // [1, 3, 6, 6, 8, 9]
```

There are **some differences** though, e. g. regarding the default compare function:

> [TypedArray.prototype.sort] performs a numeric comparison rather than the string comparison used in [Array.prototype.sort].

```js
console.log(new Array([1, 10, 2]).sort()); // [1, 10, 2]
console.log(new Int32Array([1, 10, 2]).sort()); // [1, 2, 10]
```

Comment: Where is that quote from? [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/sort) has no mention of that, aside from a comment in example code (which is hardly a part of spec).

Comment: @riv It's from the linked spec, under section 22.2.3.25 - http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%25typedarray%25.prototype.sort